# execute external php via cron

Tags: php

I have a script on my shared hosting. When i execute the script it checks if there are new members on the site. If so, the script headers to my windows server with two get parameters and a script there will execute and make a useracount for the new user. this works manualy and for 1 user just fine, however, i want to add cron to this so it runs every 15 minutes. this is'nt the problem when there is one user, but is the script has more then one user, it wont reach there becouse of the header. How can i fix this?

my code:

```
$array =  $arr->invoices->invoice;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!order_is_active($value->id)) {
        $username_win = strtolower($value->firstname) . rand(9,9999);
        $password_win = ucfirst(maakpass(10, TRUE, TRUE));
        if (add_user_to_db($value->id, $value->userid, $value->status, $username_win, $password_win)) {
            header('location: http://ip/adduper/?username=' . htmlspecialchars($username_win) . '&password=' . htmlspecialchars($password_win));
        } else {
            echo 'order bestaat al';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all of the users in an array and then send the [`json encoded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) string to your other server which will then [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to get back an array. It can then loop over the array and add each user.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a header, I'd move toward doing [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php)

This will allow you to more cleanly return from the Windows machine a status of success or failure.  As with all remote connections, you have to account for when one machine can't connect to the other.....and it isn't a matter of if that case will happen, but when.  Such is the nature of the Internet.

With a PHP header, a failed connection would create all sorts of chaos.